I'm trying to send a post request to a server using axios with cookies saved in the browser but i get empty Cookie object
I'm trying to send a post request to a server using axios with cookies saved in the browser (refresh token save in response's cookie after /login request) but i get empty Cookie object.
send post request:
axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/refresh", 
           {},
           {    
              withCredentials: true,
           })

cors policy:
origins = [
    "http://localhost:3000", // is dublicate because in one moment origin turn from 127.0.0.1 to localhost
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

How i save cookie:
@router.post("/login")
async def auth_user(
    response: JSONResponse,
    request: Request,
    uow: IUnitOfWork = UOWDep,
):
    data = await request.json()
    check = await authenticate_user(uow, data['login'], data['password'])
    if check is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                            detail='Wrond login or/and password')

    access_token = create_access_token({"sub": str(check.id)})
    refresh_token = create_refresh_token({"sub": str(check.id)})

    response.set_cookie(key="user_refresh_token", value=refresh_token, secure=True, httponly=True)

    return {'access_token': access_token, 'user': {'login': check.login, 'is_admin': check.is_admin}}

How i read cookie (cookie is empty here):
@router.post("/refresh")

async def refresh_access_token(

    response: Response,

    user_refresh_token=Cookie(default=None),

    user_data: UsersSchemeGet=Depends(get_current_user_refresh),

):

    access_token = create_access_token({"sub": str(user_data.id)})



    response.set_cookie(key="user_refresh_token", value=user_refresh_token, secure=True, httponly=True)

    return {'access_token': access_token, 'user': {'login': user_data.login, 'is_admin': user_data.is_admin}}

I tried to send a request with cookies via postman and everything worked! In browser developer tools I see cookies after login response:


Does this answer your question?

Please take a look at this related answer as well
